# Chrome omnibar doesn't complete based on history very well

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

1. open chrome
2. go to omnibar and type the beginning of an unusual string into the omnibar.  In my case, `XBoneend` which does have a recent history entry.
3. omnibar suggests a bunch of google searches.

[image: Chrome Omnibar failing to find a file in my history]

If the terms I type in were common, I would tolerate some google search results.  But, if the term is super specific/rare, plus I just visited a page with that exact string the the URL & text of the page 5 minutes before, I would prefer it to show up.

So how can I make the omnibar include super high quality matches from my recent history?

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn off google search suggestions entirely for this to work.

[image: Instructions]

Since typing search terms there, and then hitting enter gets you the same result anyway, it's not much of a loss.  What you get out of it is the ability to properly, quickly search your own browsing history.

Here are behavior once you've fixed it, showing correct search results.

[image: fixed results]